# How do I pass an input to a confirmation from phpunit in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have the following testcase

```
 public function it_can_delete_all_log_files()
 { 
     .....
     .....
     static::assertSame(0, $this->artisan('log-viewer:clear'));
     .....
 }
```

Now the problem is the command asks for a confirmation (The unit tests stops and, I have to input yes or no.), I don't find a way to provide the confirmation from phpunit programmatically. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from me is to try to clear Using Programatically ..

## COMMAND TO RUN PHP ARTISAN PROGRAMATICALLY

#### Clear Cache facade value:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return '<h1>Cache facade value cleared</h1>';
});
```

#### Reoptimized class loader:

```
Route::get('/optimize', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('optimize');
    return '<h1>Reoptimized class loader</h1>';
});
```

#### Route cache:

```
Route::get('/route-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:cache');
    return '<h1>Routes cached</h1>';
});
```

#### Clear Route cache:

```
Route::get('/route-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
    return '<h1>Route cache cleared</h1>';
});
```

#### Clear View cache:

```
Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    return '<h1>View cache cleared</h1>';
});
```

#### Clear Config cache:

```
Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return '<h1>Clear Config cleared</h1>';
});
```

Comment: unfortunately none of these will wrk for OP question

Comment: what is this :\